# Chapter number in `Lenny` and roman numerals to Old Style

Tags: sectioning, chapters, oldstylenums, fncychap

Is there a way to change the chapter number in `fncychap` as well as the roman numerals in the \frontmatter to be `old style figure` style?

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChRuleWidth{1.618pt}
\ChTitleVar{\raggedright  \huge }
\ChNameVar{\raggedleft  \Huge }

\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
Hi
\newpage
\chapter{Two}
Hi
\mainmatter
\chapter{Three}
Hi
 \end{document}
```

Comment: The Lenny style, apart from being ugly, uses Times for typesetting the chapter number. Using old style figures would not make sense anyway, because of the hole in the upper line.

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest a nice chapter heading (or a few) which is compatible with old style?

Comment: You find a number of examples in the documentation of **titlesec**. There are many also usable with memoir (`texdoc MemChapStyles`).

Comment: See my work-around below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working quite nicely (at least for the chapter numbering). The only problem that I see is one of alignment.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChRuleWidth{0pt} %0.618pt for Lenny
\ChNameVar{  \Huge \bfseries  }  
\ChNumVar{\fontsize{45}{100} \rm}
\ChTitleVar{  \huge }

\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1, Chapter 1}
Hi
\newpage
\chapter{This is Chapter 2}
\section{Section 1, Chapter 2}
Hi
\mainmatter
\chapter{This is Chapter 3}
\section{Section 1, Chapter 3}
Hi
\end{document}
```